# How secure is SectionInformation.ProtectSection?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, encryption

How secure is SectionInformation.ProtectSection in terms of how easy it is to decode/decrypt?  Can a file section which has been encrypted with SectionInformation.ProtectSection be simply decrypted on another computer with SectionInformation.UnprotectSection? If not, why not?

Answer (score 4):

The key which is used to protect a section is stored in the [machine or user key store](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f5cs0acs.aspx) on the machine where the section is protected. Anyone with sufficient rights to be able to read the key from the store can decrypt the section, but it cannot be decrypted on another machine unless the key is exported from the encrypting machine and imported into the other machine.